# Password cmd switch for Telnet

Tags: networking, command-line, passwords

I'm trying to created a batch file to automatically ping routers with telnet.

My connection prompts me for password and I'm not being able to set it :

```
start "C:\Windows\System32" telnet.exe [server]
```

If I launch it as stated, telnet opens and prompts for password input.

What I have in mind :

```
start "C:\Windows\System32" telnet.exe [server] -p [password] ping [router]
```

Does anyone knows if there is a password switch for Telnet or how to workaround this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly you can't start Telnet with a pre-written script on Windows.
However, you can use some vbs to send keys. This is a horrible way but it should work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197376/is-it-possible-to-use-a-batch-file-to-establish-a-telnet-session-send-a-command

Comment: That's what I thought, tank you for the link.